# Opening email attachments with Libreoffice 7

Tags: libreoffice, evolution

I've recently changed from Libreoffice 6 to 7 on Ubuntu18 and now email (Evolution) attachments won't open, I get this message;
Access to /home/john/.cache/evolution/tmp/evolution-john-18hj2h/(filename).docx was denied.
This worked OK with version 6 and nothing else has been changed.
Attachments can be opened with Libreoffice 7 after they have been saved to any folder.
Is this a permissions problem and is there a fix?

I followed the suggestions from Jos, thank you very much for the answer but it hasn't made any difference. (I think that should be a capital R in the chown command)

After all the changes permissions on the files and directories are;
john@john-HP-ProDesk-400-G3-SFF:~/.cache/evolution$ ls -l
total 36

drwxr-xr-x  3 john john 4096 Oct 19  2018 addressbook

drwxr-xr-x  3 john john 4096 Oct 19  2018 calendar

drwx------ 49 john john 4096 Oct  3 11:43 http

drwxr-xr-x  3 john john 4096 Oct 19  2018 mail

drwxr-xr-x  3 john john 4096 Oct 19  2018 memos

drwxr-xr-x  3 john john 4096 Oct 19  2018 sources

drwxr-xr-x  3 john john 4096 Oct 19  2018 tasks

drwxrwxr-x 17 john john 4096 Oct  3 13:58 tmp

drwx------  3 john john 4096 Apr  1  2020 WebKitCache

john@john-HP-ProDesk-400-G3-SFF:~/.cache/evolution/tmp$ ls -l
total 48

drwx------ 2 john john 4096 Oct  3 13:03 evolution-john-23s6fH

drwx------ 2 john john 4096 Oct  3 13:03 evolution-john-4iPhMu

drwx------ 2 john john 4096 Oct  3 13:35 evolution-john-5Cp7aX

drwx------ 2 john john 4096 Oct  3 13:04 evolution-john-d3RkWr

drwx------ 2 john john 4096 Oct  3 13:37 evolution-john-D4N9Ck

drwx------ 2 john john 4096 Oct  3 13:30 evolution-john-jAMEOh

drwx------ 2 john john 4096 Oct  3 13:04 evolution-john-jGs4TP

drwx------ 2 john john 4096 Oct  2 09:12 evolution-john-jKPmW7

drwx------ 2 john john 4096 Oct  3 13:34 evolution-john-jyoSk5

drwx------ 2 john john 4096 Oct  3 13:09 evolution-john-taqM9C

drwx------ 2 john john 4096 Oct  3 13:35 evolution-john-TFlqNv

drwx------ 2 john john 4096 Oct  3 13:37 evolution-john-vdBm3I

It's only Libreoffice that has this problem, attached pdfs and jpgs open ok with doc viewer and image viewer.

Answer (score 1):

It is, as the message says, a permissions problem. If you want a quick solution, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo chown -r john:john ~/.cache
sudo chmod -R u+w ~/.cache
```

To find out exactly what is wrong, instead of these commands, drill down towards the inaccessible files, starting in your home directory:

```
cd .cache
ls -l
cd evolution
ls -l
cd tmp
ls -l
```

At each step, the `ls -l` command should show files and directories that are owned by user `john` and group `john`. Permissions should start with `-rw` for files and `drwx` for directories.
If the `evolution` directory is not owed by you, or is not writable by you, change that with

```
sudo chown -r john:john evolution
sudo chmod -R u+w evolution
```

(executed from the `.cache` directory); and similar for `tmp` (executed from the `evolution` directory).